# Why in my Angular-project does not replace home-page when I go to another route, and just adds the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, angular

Here is the markup of my home page. I wrote several routes, and I need to display the content of the corresponding component instead of the home page when switching to them. And I have it added from the bottom of the home, and the home content continues to be displayed.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <app-header></app-header>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <app-home></app-home>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
  <div class="row">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my app-home:

```
<app-home-news [homeImages]="homeImages"></app-home-news>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent }
];
```

There is no error, the content simply adds to the home. How to make it appear in his place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See anything which is outside `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will always be there. Like in your case `header` and `footer` only should be in main html not `home` component. Anything you to change on the basis of routing, you should be part of routing configuration.

Make the following changes

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <app-header></app-header>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- removed the home component -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
          <app-footer></app-footer>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Add the home component as the part of the routing.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent }
];
```

Note : I add the component at the root level so I left the path blank but you can as per your path like

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful about your routes and what router outlets your urls are going to populate. It's not just a case of putting a router-outlet at the bottom of each of your components to display something new...

Assuming I had a very basic  `AppComponent` template:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

... and some configured routes:

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }
{ path: 'test', component: TestComponent },
{ path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent}
```

... which just contained their own names in a p tag (home, test, and hello respectively).

The following would be true for each url:
`example.com`

## Hello

Home

`example.com/test`

## Hello

Test

`example.com/hello`

## Hello

Hello

The route has loaded the component into the router-outlet.

If my components then had router outlets of their own, we're in to child route territory, wherein you start to use urls such as `example.com/test/abc`, with your routes looking more like:

```
{
  path: 'test', 
  component: TestComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'abc', component: AbcComponent },
    { path: 'def', component: DefComponent }
  ]
}
```

Which would result - assuming the same content rules as above would look like:

`example.com/test/abc`:

## Hello

Test

Abc

`example.com/test/def`:

## Hello

Test

Def

Typically, your `AppComponent` handles your site-wide header/footer/nav/etc. with a single `router-outlet` that every other component will be loaded into, which includes your home page itself...

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }
{ path: 'sign-up', component: SignupComponent }
{ path: 'sign-in', component: SigninComponent }
```

There may well be further router-outlets in the components (as above), but it seems that what you currently WANT, most likely, is this case rather than the more complex type with nested outlets above that you currently HAVE.